# Find the rectangle being clicked on in png with python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a png containing rectangles. I want to display this png so that the user can click inside one of the rectangles and the returned value is the top left and bottom right coordinates in pixels of the rectangle.

Here is a representative image.
[image: Warehouse shelving floor plan]

I've tried to figure out how to do this in opencv using the blob detection and mapping the mouse click coordinates to one of the blobs but I keep hitting brick walls with getting opencv to install and work. Is opencv the right library to use in this case?

The following code only finds about 8 blobs

```
# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("/home/mainmeister/PycharmProjects/WarehousrLineMap/public/warehouse.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Set up the detector with default parameters.
parameters = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
parameters.filterByColor = 1
parameters.blobColor = 255
#detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(parameters)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
#im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]),(255,0,0),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is or what the constraints are. Have you thought of using a clickable image on a web-page https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp Or do you maybe have multiple, unknown maps? Have you considered flood-filling the rectangles of interest with different colours and then detecting the colour where user clicks?

Comment: Step 1: get the pixel coordinate the user clicked on. Step 2, find the rectangle that pixel is inside of in your image. Step 3: get that rectangle's top-left corner. Step 4: we're done. So which of those steps isn't working? Because being able to focus on the exact part that's not working lets you find a solution for just that part.

Comment: please also take the [tour]

Answer (score 2):

Apply "connected components labeling" (with stats). This may require some preprocessing (thresholding). The labeling gives you an "image" containing a "label" (number) for each pixel.

Then if you click on any pixel, you can immediately look up its bounding box.

[image]

Video: https://imgur.com/a/vSnnjSE (the green box is made larger for visualization)

Some of the core logic:

```
floorplan = cv.imread("14rgT.png")
(height, width) = floorplan.shape[:2]

lower = (192,) * 3
upper = (255,) * 3
mask = cv.inRange(floorplan, lower, upper)

(nlabels, labels, stats, centroids) = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask)

# the_label = labels[y,x] # mouse click coordinates
# (x0,y0,w,h,area) = stats[the_label] # bounding box, true area in pixels
```

The rest is GUI.

This is sensitive to "rooms" having a proper, contiguous perimeter. Any holes in the walls will connect rooms.

You can fix that up to some extent with morphology operations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detecting blobs, you can display the image with a callback function that captures mouse clicks. When you click on the image, you can record the top-left and bottom-right coordinates of the rectangle you clicked on.

Here's how you can do it:

```
 import cv2

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global tl_x, tl_y, br_x, br_y, drawing
if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    drawing = True
    tl_x, tl_y = x, y
elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    drawing = False
    br_x, br_y = x, y
    cv2.rectangle(img, (tl_x, tl_y), (br_x, br_y), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    print(f"Top-left coordinates: ({tl_x}, {tl_y}), Bottom-right coordinates: ({br_x}, {br_y})")

# Read image
img = cv2.imread("G:\ITI\yy.png")

# Create a window to display the image
cv2.namedWindow("Image")

# Initialize variables
tl_x, tl_y, br_x, br_y = -1, -1, -1, -1
drawing = False

# Set the mouse callback function
cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", mouse_callback)

# Display the image
cv2.imshow("Image", img)

# Wait until a key is pressed
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Destroy all OpenCV windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

sample for output

```
Top-left coordinates: (489, 388), Bottom-right coordinates: (489, 388)
Top-left coordinates: (284, 329), Bottom-right coordinates: (284, 329)
Top-left coordinates: (200, 151), Bottom-right coordinates: (200, 151)
```

this is image for output
[image]

Comment: this solution collects two mouse positions. it is not sensitive to the image content.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest get the corners in the image first using **Harris Corner detection** ([OpenCV example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d0d/tutorial_py_features_harris.html)).

[image: Corner Image]

As you can see the corners are detected properly. If not I would suggest play with the parameters documented in OpenCV.

NOTE: The above is just for demonstration and you may need some pre-processing such as erosion and/or noise removal (if required) as well but that is empirical and I am leaving it to you.

Now just get the co-ordinate of the mouse-click (check Fatema's answer how tl_x and tl_y is obtained) and check which of the corners that you have obtained from the Harris-Corner detection step is closest. If you want the top-left then check only in above and left of the point of click.

If there is a possibility of spurious clicks (by mistake) then add a threshold on the distance from the point of click in x-y direction up to which you will check for corners.

**Alternate approach**
I haven't used this but you can try out the *scikit-image* implementation of Harris Corner detection and then extract peaks from the image as shown [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_corner.html) using *corner_peaks*. This looks to be more convenient.

Comment: I find that to be a roundabout approach. detecting corners does not get you closer to a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't get you closer to the solution"? I think what is asked in the question is the top-left and bottom right corner of the rectangle on which the mouse-click event occurs. I have mentioned how to do that in the paragraph following the "NOTE".